# How can i have a round corners on QuickLaunch SharePoint 2010

Tags: navigation

Any ideas on how i can have round corners for QuickLaunch SharePoint 2010.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Round corners on what part of the quicklaunch? Please also provide info regarding if you're using HTML5 and/or CSS3 etc.

Comment: Also, what browsers do your users use? They are easy ways in Chrome/Firefox, and hard ways in IE.

Comment: Browser is mainly IE.
Also its reagrding to have a rounded corner look for the left navigation menu - Quicklaunch

Answer (score 3):

Add this css rule:

```
#s4-leftpanel-content {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

It works in CSS3 (Firefox, Chrome, Safari already use this), even IE9 can handle CSS3, but the default master page has directive to use IE8 mode, which doesn't understand CSS3. To override this you can set IE8 i head in your masterpage:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

But beware about some [shortcomings in Sharepoint with IE=9](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/master-page-for-html5-and-css3/)

Comment: Thanks Anatoly but it doesn't work both in Firefix and IE 7+
Any ideas

Comment: What Firefox version? I have used this css rule in FF4++. 
IE8-- won't work.